# Zend: Using forms in modules

Tags: zend-framework, module, zend-form

I'm trying to use forms with modules, they should be stored inside the module. So at first my filestructure:

```
application/
   (...other directories)
   modules/
       group/
          controllers/
             IndexController.php
             (...controllers)
          forms/
             Create.php
          views/
             scripts/
                (...view scripts)
          Bootstrap.php
```

Within the IndexController, I'm trying to set the Form by

```
new Group_Form_Create()
```

and the class in Create.php is of course Group_Form_Create. I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Group_Form_Create' not found in (...)\application\modules\group\controllers\IndexController.php on line 380
```

The Bootstrap.php with the class Group_Bootstrap is just an empty class.
Actually, I'm using the default Zend structure, but it woun't work anyway. Any ideas wheres the problems or what could be a possible solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my module bootstrap (APPLICATION_PATH/modules/group/Bootstrap.php), if use the following code:

```
    //Loads the autoloader resources
    $this->_moduleName = 'group';
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH ."/modules/".$this->_moduleName."/",
            'namespace' => '',
            'resourceTypes' => array(
                    //Tells the application where to find the forms
                    'form' => array(
                            'path' => 'forms/',
                            'namespace' => ucfirst($this->_moduleName).'_Form_'
                    ),
                    //Tells the application where to find the models
                    'model' => array(
                            'path' => 'models/',
                            'namespace' => ucfirst($this->_moduleName).'_Model_'
                    )
            )
    ));
```

I then call the forms or models like this:

```
$frm = new Group_Form_Create();
```

I use the same snippet in all my modules and I only change the value of the $this->_moduleName; each time.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Same problem here: The site is gonna be an high-performance system with not only one module and the Group_Bootstrap is for some reason not executed. Any idea why?

Comment: In you main ini config file, did you add the line resources.modules="" ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your module bootstraps are not being run. These are triggered by the module resource, which is loaded if you have:

```
resources.modules[] = ""
```

in your `application.ini`. So add this if it is not present.

Comment: That's it, thank you ;-) Consider your answer as my accepted answer, even if the main point of my problem was something different, it really helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, it should work out of box.

Add this in your bootstrap:

```
protected function _initAutoload() {

    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => 'Group_',
        'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__),
      ));

    Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
    return $autoloader;
```

}

Comment: Works with `APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/group/'` as basePath, but only in the main bootstrap, not in the one of the module. Any ideas how to bring this to work in the Group_Bootstrap? Would be much better for the performance. I suppose the Group_Bootstrap is just unused...